# Does EKM work with CNG key storage providers?

Tags: sql-server, cryptography, cng, tde, mscapi

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/extensible-key-management-ekm says :

SQL Server provides data encryption capabilities together with Extensible Key Management (EKM), using the Microsoft Cryptographic API (MSCAPI) provider for encryption and key generation.

Does this mean that EKM will only work with MSCAPI(old CSP) and not with new CNG key storage provider?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at the moment the `EKM (Extensible Key Management)` works only with `MSCAPI`.  The EKM does not have any API to communicate with CNG (OS level - yet).

It is the "holder" of the keys.  The `CNG` is key storage that serves MS Windows, being default starting with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista.

### CNG vs. EKM

The `CNG (DPAPI [CNG DPAPI][1]` is used only to protect Database Master Key (OS).  `EKM` does not use it.

[image: security type illustrations]

### From the CNG point of view

If you check the CNG architecture it specifically says it is using [Microsoft software KSP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204778(v=vs.85).aspx) for (private) keys storage.

To quote:

> CNG currently supports the storage of asymmetric private keys by
>   using the Microsoft software KSP that is included with Windows Server
>   2008 and Windows Vista and installed by default.

Even the CNG architecture image does not mention SQL Server as possibility:

[image: CNG key isolation architecture]

For more see
[Key Storage and Retrieval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204778(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Note:** all illustrations were created by Microsoft.